# Adding custom controls to Thunderbird (Extension)

Tags: xul, thunderbird

I need to add a button next to **From** tag in the messege header.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Add an overlay to `content/messenger/msgHdrViewOverlay.xul`. In it,

- Define a `button` element as a child
  of `<row id="expandedfromRow">`.
- If you probably wanted to have a new
  button alongside the reply, reply
  all, forward buttons, you should add
  a new `toolbarbutton` element as a
  child to `<toolbarpalette
  id="header-view-toolbar-palette">`.

If these steps are not clear to you, let me know, I will elaborate. Thanks.

*P.S.: These steps are for Thunderbird 3+.*